# How can I write a function to shift regression line for each Facet?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
fit<-lm(log(all$fd) ~ log(all$area))
fintercept<-fit$coefficients[[1]] #intercept
fslope<-fit$coefficients[[2]] #slope
interceptmax<-max(log(all$fd)-fslope*log(all$area))

ggplot(all, aes(x=log(area), y=log(fd))) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_abline(aes(intercept=interceptmax,slope=fslope))+ #shifted regression line
  #facet_wrap(~id)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#808080"))+
  ggsave('test.png',width=6, height=4,dpi=300)
```

This ggplot2 gives me an envelope curve (a shifted regression line). If I remove facet_wrap(~id), it works as intended. But I want the lines to be computed for every facet separately. Any suggestions how I can do this for every facet? (Similar to how using 'lm' inside ggplot2 works)

Here subset of 'all' is:

```
structure(list(fd = c(11, 7.75, 55.25, 45.25, 9.5, 89, 14.5, 
8, 84.25, 5.25, 79.5, 7.75, 71, 38.5, 242.25, 33, 32, 19, 58.5, 
249.25, 19, 72.5, 6.25, 27.0333333333333, 26.5, 81, 30, 29, 39.75, 
18.5, 64.25, 91, 4.5, 30.5, 74, 256.75, 9, 81, 27, 7.5, 107, 
26.75, 47.25, 16, 57, 37, 48.25, 48, 36, 147.25, 23.5, 42, 1.08333333333333, 
21.5, 6.51666666666667, 198, 47.5, 8.75, 16, 43.5, 34.75, 30.25, 
132.25, 2.25, 12.5, 225, 37, 17.25, 63.5, 48, 19.75, 12, 62.5, 
64, 27, 11, 72.25, 246, 27.75, 15.5, 178, 93.75, 3.75, 3, 46.25, 
4, 6.25, 5.25, 20, 44, 44.5, 1, 33, 18.25, 14.5, 29.25, 9, 33, 
133, 67), area = c(20168.2374, 432.528, 5780.8535, 1411.5435, 
543.8975, 660.447, 24995.9752, 543.8975, 2659.9178, 277.1287, 
147.8883, 153.0683, 2217.0298, 1188.8045, 4237.2205, 489.5078, 
1051.5352, 1362.3337, 1401.1836, 169.3852, 1333.8439, 1051.5352, 
29.5259, 1429.6734, 668.2169, 17068.0216, 660.447, 16860.8226, 
116.5495, 3820.2325, 784.7664, 841.7461, 1696.4422, 85.9876, 
2066.8105, 2090.1204, 121.7294, 9999.9441, 127.4274, 1152.5447, 
934.9857, 1424.4935, 1774.1419, 543.8975, 784.7664, 237.5019, 
3486.124, 1080.025, 6164.1717, 3348.8546, 236.2069, 510.2277, 
31.5979, 916.8558, 1994.2908, 3501.6639, 1152.5447, 486.9178, 
533.5376, 271.9488, 336.6985, 1103.3349, 9764.2552, 36.7778, 
2375.0191, 512.8176, 422.1681, 859.8761, 1118.8749, 237.5019, 
133.6434, 453.2479, 1787.0918, 6063.1622, 237.5019, 1383.0537, 
668.2169, 1424.4935, 621.5971, 1486.6532, 7355.5662, 984.1955, 
68.8937, 154.6223, 116.5495, 1665.3624, 43.5118, 450.6579, 510.2277, 
1494.4231, 404.0381, 598.2873, 339.2884, 12406.043, 274.5387, 
151.2553, 753.6865, 29059.6666, 3470.5841, 1885.5113), id = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("Csb", "Dfb(E)", "Dfa", "Cfa"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("fd", 
"area", "id"), row.names = c("65775", "61848", "11286", "22467", 
"34601", "53841", "14661", "8941", "88607", "47681", "7898", 
"9598", "40615", "35550", "70985", "64634", "43864", "88065", 
"37520", "100794", "74916", "76759", "48928", "17575", "7424", 
"30848", "53970", "65662", "27392", "82248", "48004", "93560", 
"51147", "42321", "30070", "22096", "25575", "49067", "23702", 
"65877", "53617", "90727", "59449", "34568", "48155", "96101", 
"31358", "40150", "75458", "71566", "1687", "86603", "77451", 
"68075", "14478", "69151", "66028", "77394", "68580", "16328", 
"26945", "73615", "24179", "19497", "82448", "25098", "23565", 
"8113", "66312", "96062", "60313", "34767", "97877", "48598", 
"96135", "36877", "7309", "71065", "49622", "65051", "55340", 
"105109", "26480", "4550", "18935", "61714", "31667", "55035", 
"27563", "17332", "35694", "20092", "44334", "21344", "22303", 
"64816", "12814", "12391", "52770", "84979"), class = "data.frame")
```

Follow up to: [How can I shift the regression line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32768982/how-can-i-shift-the-regression-line?noredirect=1#comment53378053_32768982)

Comment: Are you just trying to do the same math you did for the combined model for each `id` separately?

Comment: @aosmith Basically a different line for each facet. Each ID separately that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to have a different line per facet, you can calculate the slope and desired intercept separately for each id.  It's often easiest to simply make a new dataset of the desired values and use it in `geom_abline`.  This new dataset needs to contain an `id` column as well as the values to plot so you can get separate info per facet.

There are lots of ways that you could go about creating this dataset, including fitting the regressions one by one and collecting the values "by hand".  I'll use functions from package *dplyr* to calculate the regression per `id`, save the slope, and calculate the new intercept using your formula.

```
    library(dplyr)

    all2 = all %>%
        group_by(id) %>%
        do({model = lm(log(fd) ~ log(area), data = .)
        data.frame(fslope = coef(model)[2], interceptmax = max(log(.$fd) - coef(model)[2]*log(.$area)))
        })
    all2

Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
Groups: id [4]

      id     fslope interceptmax
  (fctr)      (dbl)        (dbl)
1    Csb -0.5556930    8.3703705
2 Dfb(E)  0.5378457    0.5057893
3    Dfa  0.1227013    4.6143276
4    Cfa  0.3247770    3.3895178
```

Now use the new dataset in `geom_abline`.

```
ggplot(all, aes(x=log(area), y=log(fd))) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_abline(data = all2, aes(intercept=interceptmax, slope=fslope)) + #shifted regression line
    facet_wrap(~id) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#808080"))
```

The resulting plot has different lines for each facet.

[image]